# Removing pane causing NullPointerException with java swing

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to clear a pane and put a new one in its place with swing. But with my current setup, it throws a NullPointerException that I don't understand. Here is my code:

```
public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Generator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel pane1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel pane2 = new JPanel();

    addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane(), pane1, pane2);

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I have an actionlistener for a button in addComponentsToPane:

```
    buttonGenerate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            Map<String,String> replacements = new HashMap<String,String>(10);
            replacements.put("name", textName.getText());

            //createTable();
            //makeDocx(replacements);
            removePane();
        }
    });
```

Here is the removePane() function:

```
    public static void removePane () {
    pane1.removeAll();
}
```

pane1 has been declared `public static JPanel pane1 = null;` at the beginning of the class. When i click the button with the actionlistener, it throws `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException` directed at `pane1.removeAll();`.

Why is this error popping up? I know there is something important i am missing, does anyone know what it is or know of an alternative way to accomplish what I want?

Thanks

Comment: if pane1 is null and if you call pane1.somemethod() then its obviuos that it will throw nullpointerexception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If pane1 is a static variable, then you should reference it in your createAndShowGUI() method. You are incorrectly creating a new local reference:

```
public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Generator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel pane1 = new JPanel(); //INCORRECT
```

Instead, use your static reference:

```
public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Generator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pane1 = new JPanel(); //CORRECT
```

Comment: That makes sense. Now when i click the button that removes the pane, it just stays in the click position and nothing happens. I am guessing since it is on the pane that is being removed, a problem is occuring. Any solutions?

Comment: @Cole, it should be `revalidate()` and don't use static variables and methods. This may answer your question, but it is NOT a good way to design a GUI.

Comment: How would i make a removable pane without the static declaration at the beginning? Forgive, i am learning java as i go along.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use static variables and methods. That is NOT the way to design a GUI.

Maybe start with a simple example like the `ButtonDemo` from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). Then you add `instance` variables to the class that you can access from your listeners.

> Now when i click the button that removes the pane, it just stays in the click position and nothing happens

When you remove (or add) components to a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.remove();
panel.revalidate(); // to invoke the layout manager
panel.repaint(); // sometimes needed to force a repaint of the panel
```

Comment: `How would i make a removable pane without the static declaration at the beginning?` - start by looking at the tutorial. The class extend a JPanel, so you can create and add as many panels as you wish. You can define each panel as an instance variable, just like the class currently does for each button.

Answer (score 3):

By doing:

```
JPanel pane1 = new JPanel();
```

You are creating a second local variable in createAndShowGUI called pane1. You are not using the global variable defined as static. That one is still null. You should create it like this:

```
pane1 = new JPanel();
```